# How Does the Blockchain Use Hashes?

Tags: plutus, hash, encryption

Hash functions are often called one way functions however this means that you should not be able to undo them. So why and how are SHA256 and SHA512 used in blockchains if they should be irreversible.

Also I noticed that Plutus has some unhasing functions how do these work?

Comment: The hash function in plutus is also a one-way function. I think that the `unHash` function that is meant here is the type constructor of a Hash type. `unHash` serves here to unwrap the type to, probably, a `builtinByteString`. Can you point to this `unHash` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cardano code does not use SHA256 or SHA512, but rather uses 2 different versions of the Blake2 hash functions (but Plutus may use SHA hashes).

Hash functions are used in several places. Two simple examples are block ids (ie the hash of the block) and transaction ids (the hash of the transaction). For these two examples reversing the hash is never needed.

I am almost certain that the Plutus "unhashing" function you see is just the accessor for the `newtype` wrapper (its a Haskell/Plutus thing).

Answer (score 1):

Cardano does not use SHA256 hashing. There are **BLAKE2b** cryptographic hashing algorithms in Cardano, and the following table represents three of them:

---

| Hashing Algorithm | Referred as | Used for |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BLAKE2b-224 | hash28 | Verification keys and multi-signature scripts |
| BLAKE2b-256 | hash32 | Used everywhere else in Cardano |
| BLAKE2b-512 | hash64 | Used for key derivations |